# React format date invalid time value

Tags: reactjs

I have the below code where I convert the `startDate`.

```
import React from "react";
import type { RoomBooking } from "../../services/room/room";
import format from "date-fns/format";
    
export const BookingList = ({ bookings }: { bookings: RoomBooking[] }) => (
<ul>
{bookings.map((booking, index) => (
 <li key={`booking-${index}`}>
  {format(new Date(booking.startDate), "dd/MM/yyyy")}
 </li>
))}
</ul>
);
```

With this code I have this error `RangeError: Invalid time value`, when I log the `bookings` list I find it empty, so how can I check if the booking is not null?

Answer (score 0):

You could do check it like this if you want provide a default date

```js
{format(new Date(booking?.startDate || ""), "dd/MM/yyyy")}
```

Even better might be to

```js
{
  booking?.startDate ?
    format(new Date(booking.startDate), "dd/MM/yyyy") :
    "No date"
}
```